# Is it good practice to only use LinearLayout for a Layout that only plans on using one screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a screen in my Android Application that only takes up one screen. Because of this, I thought it would be really quick and easy to just use LinearLayout as my base layout:
[image]

I thought this would be good. However, I am thinking, what if someone uses a 2.7 inch screen on their smartphone? Or they do split view. They might not be able to see everything without scrolling. So, is it good practice to do the layout the way I am doing it or is it always good to allow the user to scroll to see everything?

Comment: Just wrap your layout with ScrollView and you all set. It will be scrollable only if view doesnt fit

Comment: @VygintasB Just a question. Why don't you put that in an answer instead of a comment? Then I can accept your answer and we both win?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since many different devices exist, some with very tiny or otherwise abnormal screens, it is a good idea to make the layout scrollable when needed.

This is achieved by encapsulating your layout in a ScrollView.

Other popular methods to tackle this are using ConstraintLayouts, or the legacy Relativelayouts, which are placed *relatively* to each other, and relative to screen borders.

What if a layout gets partially off-screen? Maybe it is no big deal, but maybe it hides an essential part of the layout (e.g. a 'next' button, or some important information). So yes, your worry is justified.

As I believe it is good practice to make an app work on as many different phones as possible, I do believe it is good practice to make sure a layout does not appear partially off-screen.